# R default encoding to UTF-8

Tags: r, encoding

How to configure Rprofile in 'library\base\R' so that default charset is UTF-8 rather than native.

The encoding configured as line

```
options(encoding = "native.enc")
```

I suppose in place of native.enc, we need to put UTF-8 relevant value.

Comment: Don't touch to "library\base\R". Create your local Rprofile file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As from R 3.0.0 the encoding "UTF-8-BOM" is accepted for reading and will remove a Byte Order Mark if present (which it often is for files and webpages generated by Microsoft applications). If a BOM is required (it is not recommended) when writing it should be written explicitly, e.g. by writeChar("\ufeff", con, eos = NULL) or writeBin(as.raw(c(0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)), binary_con)

Encoding names "utf8", "mac" and "macroman" are not portable, and not supported on all current R platforms. "UTF-8" is portable and "macintosh" is the official (and most widely supported) name for ‘Mac Roman’.

[More Info](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html)

Comment: Thank You. edited the Rprofile file encoding line to 'options(encoding = "utf-8")' now R is using utf-8 as default encoding.