# How to change the default text encoding in R?

Tags: r

How do I change the default text encoding in R CLI on Mac? This seems to be pretty simple but googling has not yielded much  :-). Any tips would be appreciated. In `RStudio`, you can change it by following these steps: `RStudio -> Preferences -> General -> Default text encoding -> Change`

Comment: Did you look at `options?`  See also [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31309002/1305688).

Comment: @EricFail, yeah I did and nothing is in there. I am using R 3.2.3 by the way.

Comment: The goal is to write a file with a specific encoding? Could you say a bit more about the desired behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use a GUI for R. Still, it's not clear to me what you are looking to do.

Comment: @EricFail, OK forget GUI then and how do you do it from the command line??